# VS2010 Extensibility: Custom document formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

Good afternoon,

I've created a visual studio package that registers the Verilog language as a valid content type.

I've got syntax highlighting, outlining, smart indenting, etc all working.

However, I would like to be able to get Visual Studio to automatically format the entire document via `Edit->Advanced->Format Document/Selection`.  Currently these options are invisible, and I expect that I have to let VS2010 know (somehow) that these methods can be called, and provide the correct methods to do this formatting.

I can't seem to find any reference to formatting in the VS2010 SDK and documentation.  I was hoping that `ISmartIndent` would be the solution I was looking for, but it seems that this code only runs on an empty line, or when the enter key is pressed.

Does anyone have any tips or ideas on how I can solve this problem?

Thanks,

Giawa

Edit:  I'm using the managed extension framework introduced with VS2010 to accomplish this.  I'm writing in C# (and just added the c# tag to my question).  Thanks

Comment: Is there anyway you can post your extension to codeplex? Sounds pretty cool and others may benefit from it too.

Comment: @Mrchief:  I'd love to, but it will depend on my employer.  They might let me post some of the cooler snippets (such as syntax highlighting of comment blocks using the MEF).

Comment: Have you taken a look at [the MSDN section on "Reformatting Code"?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164633.aspx) (specifically, [`ProvideLanguageServiceAttribute.EnableFormatSelection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.providelanguageserviceattribute.enableformatselection.aspx)).

Comment: Haven't seen this article - looking into it.  The MPF seems quite a bit different than the MEF (which I'm currently using).  It looks like I probably should have taken the MPF approach for implementing full fledged language support.  I'm checking to see if they're compatible, but I don't see why they wouldn't be.

Comment: @James McNellis:  It looks like I do need to use MPF, which is most unfortunate.  A lot of my code has to be re-written for the language service.  Anyways, your suggestion was correct.  You could submit it as an answer if you'd like, and I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MEF is not the right way to accomplish the task of creating a language service.  Instead, the Managed Package Framework (MPF) should be used to register the language service and perform tasks such as syntax highlighting, outlining, parsing, formatting, parsing, etc.

Since my question was about formatting, I'll cover a little bit of it in my answer.  You must override the [ReformatSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.source.reformatspan.aspx) method in the custom [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.source.aspx) object that you've creating for your language service.  There's a good example on the [MSDN webpages for VS2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164633%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (applicable to VS2010 as well).

You can also force formatting at any time by calling the ReformatSpan method directly.  Here's a working example from my code:

```
Region region = service.GetRegionContainingLine((line > 0 ? line - 1 : 0));

if (region != null)
{
    using (EditArray mgr = new EditArray(this, service.LastActiveTextView, true, "Reformat Brace"))
        this.ReformatSpan(mgr, region.ToSpan());
}
```

Thanks to @[James McNellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151292/james-mcnellis) for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee197665.aspx

Comment: I've already got full outlining support, which allows to editor to collapse blocks of code (such as comments/modules/etc in Verilog).  This is also what I use in Smart Indenting, but it doesn't help me with my problem of making 'Format Document' and 'Format Selection' available...

Comment: Could it be associated with linking extension to content?

Comment: Also, I think it has something to do with creating your own language service provider. Don't have any exact references though...

Comment: I've already linked the extension to content without any problem.  I just need to figure out how to export the correct methods for Visual Studio to know that Format Document/Selection are available for this contentType.